# free server for small files used in an application

Tags: server, host

For specific reasons I need to store a small files (up to 1MB) in a web server so that my application can read data from it. I don't need any server side computing. I know there are commercial solutions for this but since this is a test app I need to manage costs down. Does any one know a free solution to store files like a server? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Python installed on the computer, just go to the directory where you have the files and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` - it will start a HTTP server on port 8000.

If you want this to be hosted online, then you can use any number of free services:

1. Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive - upload the file there an use their API or a simple direct link to it.
2. Use Amazon S3 - its available for free for 12 months if you are a new subscriber.

Comment: I need to share this app with a few friends for testing. I need an online solution.

Comment: Well I found this site and it is good for my purpose: hostinghood.com

Answer (score 0):

If you need that to speed up your website, you can use CDN at:
https://www.cloudflare.com/
It stores automatucly your website's static data.